# Low sound on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04

ever since I have been upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 Kubuntu, the sound volume is very low. I have thought the reason would be the same as it was in 14.04 and went to "alsamixer" to check, but there everything is set up to 100% and looks correctly. Also the volume settings for the sound adapter are set up correctly and the volume to 100%. I have also made sure that in the volume control of the KDE Desktop, the sound of the used app (i.e. Firefox, Games, etc.) is set to 100 percent.

The sound quality itself is good... the sounds is clear and nice as well.. it is just hard to hear.

I am using an HP Laptop with onboard Intel Sound. It worked fine on Windows 8 and 10 like a year ago and it worked well on a Testversion of 15.10 and later on on 14.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar issue and found that it was related to the Pulse Audio settings.
There are various ways to adjust these, but the one I used and works very well was to install a gui utility called pavucontrol (PulseAudio Volume Control)

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

This application gives much more control than the default volume control in the system tray, including ability to increase volume above "100 %".

Answer (score 1):

There's a danger that you have some competing audio controller in place, or that you don't know the correct name of the device you are trying to adjust.  Recently, we saw a case where alsamixer was installed, along with an Ubuntu unity desktop and pavucontrol.  Also, the separately sound players like rhythmbox and vine had their own volume adjusters.  It seems as though if one of these is set to a low value, turning the others up to max does not help. In our case, the alsamixer setting was muted, but none of the other device controllers noticed and we had no warning.